# Facebook OAuth Login via web api returns invalid_request

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api, oauth

I am trying to use Facebook OAuth to authenticate user login in a asp.net web api app.

I am redirected to this page **"https://www.facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php"** get this error **"Your request could not be processed.
Please try again"** when logging in via the returned HTML from the ChallengeResult in the web api when hitting the **api/Account/ExternalLogin** endpoint.

I've already updated the **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** NuGet package in the web api but still having the error. I assume that this is a bug (thinking).

I've read an article about external OAuth authentication from:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/ but I still get the error.

Any workaround with this? This is my first time working with this.